# ES giving error when sorting by distance

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, geo, foselasticabundle

I'm trying to sort search results by distance.  However, when i try i get the following error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "sort option [location] not supported"
         }
      ],
      "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason": "all shards failed",
      "phase": "query",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [
         {
            "shard": 0,
            "index": "roeselaredev",
            "node": "2UYlfd7sTd6qlJWgdK2wzQ",
            "reason": {
               "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
               "reason": "sort option [location] not supported"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

The query i sent looks like this:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": [] 
    },
    "sort": [

        {
            "geo_distance": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 50.9436034,
                    "long": 3.1242917
                },
                "order":"asc",
                "unit":"km",
                "distance_type":"plane"
            }
        },
        {
            "_score": {
                "order":"desc"   
            }        
        }
    ]
}
```

As near as i can tell i followed the instructions in the documentation to the letter.  I'm not getting a malformed query result.  I'm just getting a not supported result for the sort by distance option.  Any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How is mapped `geo_distance` ?

Comment: geo_distance is the name of the filter, it's not mapped.  

location is mapped like so:
`location: { type: geo_point, property_path: esGetLocation }`  The esGetLocation method simply returns a string containing lat and long joined (seperated by a comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query dsl is invalid the OP is almost-correct :) but missing an under-score.

While sorting by distance it is [_geo_distance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html) and not `geo_distance`.

Example:

```
GET _search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": [] 
    },
    "sort": [

        {
            "_geo_distance": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 50.9436034,
                    "long": 3.1242917
                },
                "order":"asc",
                "unit":"km",
                "distance_type":"plane"
            }
        },
        {
            "_score": {
                "order":"desc"   
            }        
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: gah :p Much obliged!